# transformation of evenly spaced rectangular set of point

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, transformation

I have a set of evenly spaced point that forms a rectangle (sorry for the bad drawing, imagine all points are evenly spaced), and applying an angle, i want to go from left picture to right picture. The only point that does NOT move are the bottom left and the top right.

I guess i can deduce new locations of each point using tangent to get dx and dy. But i am not sur that i will end up with exactly what i want. And there may be a more elegent transformation to apply on each point ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So we want to preserve two opposite vertices of rectangle and diagonal between them.

Let half-width of rectangle is `w`, half-height `h`, circle radius `r`. Let coordinate origin is at circle center.

Angle between diagonal and OX is

```
theta = atan(h/w)
```

After transformation angle between  diagonal and low edge of new rectangle is

```
fi = alpha + theta
```

So we can find half-width of new rectangle

```
nw = r * cos(fi)
```

And coordinates of shifted vertex are

```
2*nw*cos(alpha) - w, -h - 2*nw*sin(alpha)
```

We want to find affine tranformation **M** that transform two vertices to the same points and the third vertex into coordinates above

```
    |-w  w   w|   |-w  w  2*nw*cos(alpha) - w |
M * |-h  h  -h| = |-h  h  -h - 2*nw*sin(alpha)|
    |1   1   1|   |1   1                     1|
```

To find **M**, we make inversion of the left matrix and multiply both sides by this inverse.

```
M = |nw*cos(alpha)/w     w/h - nw*cos(alpha)/h    0|
    |-nw*sin(alpha)/w    1 +  nw*sin(alpha)/h     0|
    |0                   0                        1|
```

Now we can transform all coordinates with this matrix and get rotated rectangle.

Example of coordinate transformation from my Delphi program generating picture below:

```
  nX := Round(cx + x * cos(alpha)*nw/w + y * (w/h - cos(alpha)*nw / h));
  nY := Round(cy - x * nw/w*sin(alpha) + y * (1 + nw/h * sin(alpha)));
```

[image]

Comment: impossible ? it is surly not a simple rotation but there might be something adaptive that move the point regarding to, say, its distance to the rectangle diagonal or something else !?
I actually already did what you propose but it does not fit my needs. Maybe i could add to it an other transformation that strech/shrink the axises

Comment: So you want to preserve exact position of one diagonal and change aspect ratio of rectangle?